# FTP server breaks connection before download is complete

Tags: python, ftplib

Sometimes, FTP server closes connection before file is completely downloaded..

Here is my code:

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(site)
ftp.login(user, pw)
ftp.cwd(dir)
remotefiles = ftp.nlst()
for file in remotefiles:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, match_text):
        if os.path.exists(file):
            if True: print file, 'already fetched'
        else:
            if True: print 'Downloading', file
            local = open(file, 'wb')                
            try:            
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file, local.write)
            finally:
                local.close()                       
            if True: print 'Download done.'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify a `timeout` parameter in the `FTP` constructor and set it to 0 or something very large value like *sys.maxint*.

> `class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])`

[image]

Additionally, you can turn on debugging to see what's going on behind the scenes.

```
ftp = ftplib.FTP(site, user, pw, timeout=0)
ftp.set_debuglevel(2)
```

Hope this helps.